# how to tag an existing AWS autoscaling group with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to tag an existing autoscaling group, using Python and Boto3.

I can definitely describe the ASGs by name:

```
import boto3
asg_client = boto3.client("autoscaling")
asg_name = "foo-bar20220502044025104700000001"
response = asg_client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(AutoScalingGroupNames=[asg_name])
```

The problem I have with the `create_or_update_tags()` and `delete_tags()` methods is that they don't seem to accept a list of ASG names. E.g. this doesn't work:

```
asg_client.create_or_update_tags(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[asg_name],
    Tags=[my_tag]
)
```

To make it clear:

- the ASG already exists, I am not creating it here
- I do not want to make any other changes to the ASG
- all I want is be able to tag an ASG if I know its name
- I need to use boto3 from Python for this

The tag-related methods appear to be different from all the other ASG client methods in that they do not accept an ASG name, or list of names, as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, you just need provide a different input. The `ResourceId` of these client methods can be supplied with an ASG name.

[Here is the boto3 docs for the `create_or_update_tags` call.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.create_or_update_tags)

Here's an example:

```
asg_client.create_or_update_tags(
    Tags=[
        {
            'ResourceId': asg_name,
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Key': 'myTagKey',
            'Value': 'myTagValue',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True
        },
    ]
)
```

Comment: Doh! Coding all day, I ended up not noticing it. So obvious now. Thank you!